# What to pass for unneeded ref variables?

Tags: c#, ref

I'm working with a GIS based math library that wraps lower C/C++ code in C#. Many of the parameters are pass by reference for the sake of receiving multiple outputs. If I only want some of the outputs, how can I ignore the other parameters? Is the best solution to create a dummy variable and pass it by reference and ignore its output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the best solution to create a dummy variable and pass it by reference and ignore its output?

Yes, that's what I do.

Comment: It seems so unnecessary. I've been using it, but I'm open to change.

Comment: It's not unnecessary because for all you know the function uses the variable during it's calculations, eg. the variable is necessary to the function if not to you.

Answer (score 1):

I usually just create an object in my code like

```
object NotNeeded = null;
```

or something similar that says that its effectively an unnecessary parameter and then use that repeatedly. I'm not sure whether or not that'll work, though, because I'm not sure what the GIS library is doing on the other side. If it needs an actual non-null value for each one, that might be problemeatic.

Comment: In the instance that spawned this question, you pass it a file and through ref parameters you get all sorts of info about the field data in the file. Passing null would have been fine this time, but I do see your concern. There are other places I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few choices:

- dummies
- wrapper methods
- change the Interop Imports. Your `ref` parameters are most likely pointers in C++, and if they allow `null` then you could change the import to use pointers (IntPtr) and pass `null` / `IntPtr.Zero`.

But a few dummies is probably the best (easiest to read) option unless you have really many, many calls.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" is the "only" compile-time method that I am aware of: `foo(bar, ref dummy)` -- but feel free to wrap away these dummy variables if it makes sense.

If there are instance methods, creating appropriate [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) wrappers can help hide the "useless" dummy variables in a relatively seamless fashion.

Happy coding.

Comment: Sadly they're static methods, unless can you add extensions to a static class? I don't think you can...

Comment: @Corey Ogburn One cannot :-) However, there are multiple ways to wrap access, including using a custom wrapper class and funneling all access through that. The amount of total effort vs. gain should be considered, but it may be another option.

Comment: I don't know... that'd make it a wrapper around a wrapper. For this instance, effort vs. gain results in me just using dummy variables.